# How can i save active button after reload?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can u please help me. There is a menu with buttons, when i click on a button, id of button save in cookies and then page reload with a new content-relevant button. Requires that the button remains active. :)

JS:

```
function initBrandSelector() {
  $('.tab button').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var brand = $(this).val();
    if (brand) {
      $.cookie('current_brand', brand, {'path': '/', 'expires': 365});

    } else {
      $.removeCookie('current_brand', {'path': '/'});
    }

    location.reload(true);

    $(this).addClass("active")

    return true;
  });
}


$(document).ready(function(){
  initBrandSelector();
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="tab">
  {% for brand in brands %}
  <button class="tablinks" value="{{ brand.id }}">
          {{ brand.brand_name }}
  </button>
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Comment: Your code does not contain any attempt at reading back the cookie.

Comment: @ChrisG for the load content i read back the cookie at django view

Comment: So as far as I can see, all you need to do is change your HTML view code to add the `active` class to the button if it matches the cookie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `document.ready` function check if you have the brand set in the cookie.
If you have it select, the button and add the class.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var brand = $.cookie('current_brand');
  if (!!brand) {
    $('.tab button[value=' + brand + ']').addClass("active");
  }
  initBrandSelector();
});
```

Comment: Glad I could help, please mark the question as answered if it did resolve your question.